# How to make a grid with integers in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have the following code which has to print out a board with numbers according to the size the user specified (for instance 3 means a 3 x 3 board):

```
n = d * d
    count = 1
    board = []
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(d):
            number = n - count
            if number >= 0 :
                tile = number
                board.append[tile]
            else:
                exit(1)
            count += 1
            print(board)
```

I need to get this in a grid, so that the board is 3 x 3 in size ike this:

```
8 7 6
5 4 3
2 1 0
```

What I tried to do is to get each row in a list (so [8 7 6] [5 4.. etc) and then print those lists in a grid. In order to do that, I guess I would have to create an empty list and then add the numbers to that list, stopping after every `d`, so that each list is the specified length.

I now have a list of the numbers I want, but how do I seperate them into a grid?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: This code doesn't even attempt to satisfy the requirement. Show us a decent attempt, e.g. the "thing you tried with `append`". We can help you fix that.

Comment: Okay, I edited it now!

Comment: Great. So. What's the problem with your code? Please elaborate on "didn't work". Be specific.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett  I tried being more specific. Thank you for helping me out and I hope it's better like this!

Answer (score 3):

By default the print() function adds "\n" to the end of the string you want to print. You can override this by passing in the end argument.

```
print(string, end=" ")
```

In this case we are adding a space instead of a line break.
And then we have to print the linebreaks manually with print() at the end of each row.

```
n = d * d
count = 1
max_len = len(str(n-1))
form = "%" + str(max_len) + "d"
for i in range(d):
    for j in range(d):
        number = n - count
        if number >= 0 :
            tile = number
        else:
            exit(1)
        count += 1
        print(form%(tile), end=" ") 
    print()
```

EDIT: by figuring out the maximum length of the numbers we can adjust the format in which they're printed. This should support any size of board.

Comment: Yes thank you! This is what I tried as well, but it only worked on a 3 x 3 grid, not on other sizes. How could I make it work for 4 or 5 too?

Comment: Hint - look at [format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format)

Comment: You can try print("%2d" %(tile), end=" ")

Comment: Thanks @Sam, thats' exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Here a function that takes the square size and print it.

If you need explanation don't hesitate to ask.

```
def my_print_square(d):
    all_ = d * d

    x = list(range(all_))
    x.sort(reverse=True)  # the x value is a list with all value sorted reverse.
    i=0
    while i < all_:
       print(" ".join(map(str, x[i:i+d])))
       i += d


my_print_square(5)
24 23 22 21 20
19 18 17 16 15
14 13 12 11 10
9 8 7 6 5
4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the board as a nested list, where each list is a row in the board. Then concatenate them at the end:

```
def get_board(n):
    # get the numbers
    numbers = [i for i in range(n * n)]

    # create the nested list representing the board
    rev_board = [numbers[i:i+n][::-1] for i in range(0, len(numbers), n)]

    return rev_board

board = get_board(3)

# print each list(row) of the board, from end to start
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in row) for row in reversed(board)))
```

Which outputs:

```
8 7 6
5 4 3
2 1 0
```

If you want to align the numbers for 4 or 5 sized grids, just use a `%d` format specifier:

```
board = get_board(4)

for line in reversed(board):
    for number in line:
        print("%2d" % number, end = " ")
    print()
```

Which gives an aligned grid:

```
15 14 13 12 
11 10  9  8 
 7  6  5  4 
 3  2  1  0
```